# How to identify the trigger that caused a scheduler exception?

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

I would like to identify (in Java) which trigger executed, caused an exception in quartz so that I can more accurately track problems.

Using a SchedulerListener I can identify the exception (which specifies the specific task which is useful) but there is no access to the specific trigger which ran.   In the event that I have multiple triggers on a job, I would like to be able to identify which trigger crashed out.

When the crash occurs I can query the currently executing jobs within the scheduler and hope that only 1 is running, but I would like to find a more robust solution.

Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If the exception is happening during running of a Job, you should have access to the JobExecutionContext, in the execute method, which notes the trigger that caused its execution.